# Why this code not working properly?

Tags: wordpress

I have the following function for displaying share links conditionally. So when it is homepage it displays a different list from the single page. but it works good with home, while in the single post it is not showing any thing.
her is my code

```
function social_links(){
if(is_home()){
    $bitlink = $lnk = get_bloginfo('url');
    $nam = get_bloginfo('name');
}
$current_post_id=get_the_ID();
if(is_single($post->ID)){
    $bitlink = $lnk = get_permalink($current_post_id);
    $nam = get_the_title($current_post_id);
}
$them_uri = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
$bitly = getBitly($bitlink);
$url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($current_post_id) );
echo '<div id="socialleft">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <img src="'.$them_uri.'/images/social/share-64.png" alt="مشاركة"/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='.$lnk.'&amp;t='.$nam.'" title="" target="_blank">
            </li>
                    <img src="'.$them_uri.'/images/social/facebook-64.png" alt="شارك على فيسبوك" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://twitter.com/home/?status='.$nam.' : '.$bitly.'" title="" target="_blank">
                    <img src="'.$them_uri.'/images/social/twitter-64.png" alt="غرد" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url='.$lnk.'" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,
                  \'\', \'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600\');return false;" title="" target="_blank">
                    <img src="'.$them_uri.'/images/social/Google-plus-64.png" alt="+شارك على جوجل" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='.$lnk.'&media='.esc_url( $url ).'" title="" target="_blank">
                    <img src="'.$them_uri.'/images/social/pinterest-64.png" alt="شارك على بينترست" />
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>';}
```

i'm using the function into the index.php which contains

```
<?php
  /**
  * The main template file.
  *
  * @package Brandon
  * @author Muffin group
  * @link http://muffingroup.com
  */

  get_header();
  ?>

  <!-- #Content -->
  <div id="Content">
  <div class="content_wrapper clearfix">

    <!-- .sections_group -->
    <div class="sections_group">


        <div class="section">
            <div class="section_wrapper clearfix">
                <?php
                    echo '<div class="posts_wrapper clearfix">';            
                        while ( have_posts() ){
                            the_post();
                            get_template_part( 'includes/content', get_post_type() );
                        }
                    echo '</div>';

                    // pagination
                    if(function_exists( 'rc_pagination' )):
                        rc_pagination();
                    else:
                        ?>
                            <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link(__('&larr; Older Entries', 'brandon')) ?></div>
                            <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link(__('Newer Entries &rarr;', 'brandon')) ?></div>
                        <?php
                    endif;
                ?>
            </div>  
        </div>


    </div>  

    <!-- .four-columns - sidebar -->
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    <?php render_social_links();?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your newly revised code, there are still some issues.

1. You are still using `$post->ID`
2. `get_the_ID()` will not work for the Posts Page (home page)
3. The values are not properly sanitized before rendering out to the browser.

Let me help you out here.

**Fetching the Posts Page ID**

The first step is to grab the post ID for the home page, which is the Posts Page.  Here is a function to do that:

```
/**
 * Get the posts page ID.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @return integer
 */
function get_posts_page_id() {
    $post_id = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
    if ( $post_id ) {
        return (int) $post_id;
    }

    return (int) get_queried_object_id();
}
```

**Step 2: Revising Your Code**

The next step is to initialize the permalink, post title, and post ID variables for either a single post or the Posts Page.  If there is not post ID, then there's no sense rendering the social links out.  So it bails out.

Also, to keep things separate, it's best to move the HTML out of the business logic and put it into a View file.  Here I'm including the new view file.

You'll also notice that if the post does not have a featured image, it sets it to an empty string.

```
function render_social_links() {
    $post_id = 0;

    if ( is_home() ) {
        $post_id    = get_posts_page_id();
        $permalink  = get_permalink( $post_id );
        $post_title = get_bloginfo( 'name' );
    }

    if ( is_single() ) {
        $post_id    = get_the_ID();
        $permalink  = get_permalink( $post_id );
        $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
    }

    if ( ! $post_id ) {
        return;
    }

    $theme_uri = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
    $bitly     = getBitly( $permalink );

    $featured_image_url = '';
    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post_id ) ) {
        $featured_image_id  = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
        $featured_image_url = $featured_image_id ? wp_get_attachment_url( $featured_image_id ) : '';
    }

    $permalink            = esc_url( $permalink );
    $post_title_attribute = esc_attr( $post_title );
    $post_title           = esc_html( $post_title );

    include( __DIR__ . '/views/social-links.php' );
}
```

**View File**

Next you need to create a view file that has the HTML and embedded PHP variables in it.  I've shown in the above example as being located in `views/social-links.php`.  Here is the file for you:

Notice that the file does not start with `<?php`.  Instead we are using the native HTML and then embedding the variables that you need to populate the various areas in the markup.

```
<div id="socialleft">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="<?php echo $theme_uri; ?>/images/social/share-64.png" alt="مشاركة"/>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $permalink; ?>&amp;t=<?php echo $post_title_attribute; ?>" title="" target="_blank">
                <img src="<?php echo $theme_uri; ?>/images/social/facebook-64.png" alt="شارك على فيسبوك"/>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://twitter.com/home/?status=<?php echo $post_title_attribute; ?>:<?php echo esc_url( $bitly ); ?>" title="" target="_blank">
                <img src="<?php echo $theme_uri; ?>/images/social/twitter-64.png" alt="غرد"/>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo $permalink; ?>" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;"                 title="" target="_blank">
                <img src="<?php echo $theme_uri; ?>/images/social/Google-plus-64.png" alt="+شارك على جوجل"/>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php if ( $featured_image_url ) : ?>
        <li>
            <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo $permalink; ?>&media=<?php echo esc_url( $featured_image_url ); ?>" title="" target="_blank">
                <img src="'<?php echo $theme_uri; ?>/images/social/pinterest-64.png" alt="شارك على بينترست"/>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You are gorgeous, and your answer makes more sense , but i have done all the recommendations but still not showing.i will edit my code into the question

Comment: Yes, please share what you have now and then we can further help you along with your code.

Comment: @MohamedOmar I revised my answer for your newly revised code.  Give it a try.

Comment: i have copied the two functions into the functions.php and created the social-links.php as you demonstrated but nothing at all shown in both either home or single. have you tried it yourself.

Comment: Yes, I ran it on my test site before posting.  I tested it against a single post and the Posts Page.  If nothing is being displayed, then you are not getting a post ID.  Look at the code.  It bails out if no post ID is found.

Comment: Now you need to debug within your own application to determine the root cause.  Things to check for are:  when are you calling the function.  Notice too that I change the function's name to better reflect what it does.  Make sure you are calling the ’render_social_links` in your original code.  If yes, then either run Xdebug or `var_dump` out the code to determine what is stopping it.

Comment: Thanks a lot . You have done your best so far and it seems that i have a problem . i will make my tries and inform you. Thanks you very much.

Comment: If you can't get it, then paste in the calling code too, i.e. The code that calls the `render_social_links` function.  That will help us to see the timing.  Cheers.

Comment: it worked but i had to put the function in both single.php and index.php. but i don't know why is that? because first of all i put the function directly after the `get_header` directly to make sure it will work for all pages or posts.

Answer (score 1):

```
function social_links(){
if(is_home()){
    $bitlink = get_bloginfo('url');
    $lnk = get_bloginfo('url');
    $nam = get_bloginfo('name');
    echo "You are at homepage";
}
$current_post_id=get_the_ID();
if(is_single($current_post_id)){
    $bitlink = get_permalink($post->ID);
    $lnk = the_permalink();
    $nam = the_title();
    echo "You are at single page";
}
}
```

in above function you will not display single page because single page condition not satisfied.You will try with this code.

Instead of single please check,

if (is_singular('post')) {

```
//your code here...
```

}

Please refer this link:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59979/how-to-detect-single-php-but-not-single-portfolio-php

Comment: Thanks but it haven't make any difference. still not showing

Comment: could you please print post id title while on single page.

Comment: @MohamedOmar can you share a url?I have to ask one more thing does your condition work?

Comment: it works fine in the homepage. but completely not showing the list itself at the single file

Comment: instead of home use is_front()

Comment: is_front_page() returns true if the user is on the page or page of posts that is set to the front page on Settings->Reading->Front page displays

Comment: sorry but again nothing changed